# Using boolean remove(Object o) in linked list

Tags: java

This is the `remove()` method

```
public boolean removeId(Object d) {
    boolean removed=false;
    curr=fNode; 

    if(curr==null)
      throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete");

    else if(curr.data==d) {       

        fNode=fNode.next;
        curr=fNode;
        removed=true;
      }

    else  
      curr=curr.next;


    count--;
    return removed;
}
```

The class

```
public class Hospital {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String treatType;
    private String date;

    public Hospital()  {
        id=0;
        name="NA";
        price=0;
        treatType="NA";
        date="NA";    
    }

    public Hospital(int a,String b,double c,String d,String e) {
        id=a;
        name=b;
        price=c;
        treatType=d;
        date=e;
    }

    public void setHospital(int a,String b,double c,String d,String e) {
        id=a;
        name=b;
        price=c;
        treatType=d;
        date=e;
    }

    public int getId(){ return id; }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public double getPrice(){ return price; }
    public String getTreatType(){ return treatType; }
    public String getDate(){ return date; }

    public String toString()  {
        return ("Id :"+id+"\nName :"+name+"\nPrice :"+price+"\nTreatment type :"+treatType+"\nDate :"+date);
    }
  }
```

In main

```
System.out.println("Enter id you want to remove :");
int remId=in.nextInt();

list.removeId(new Integer(remId));
```

Why isn't the id in the first node removed? I tried it to remove the first node but it does not remove it. I tried a lot of ways including change the remId to int but it still does not work.

Now, I make some changes to the `remove()` method by eliminating the 'while' and use 'equal' but it does not make any sense. Then I tried another change and it works
Why this code works?

```
public boolean removeId(Object d)
{
    boolean removed=false;

    curr=fNode;
        if(curr==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete");

        else
            {
                    fNode=fNode.next;
                    curr=fNode;
                    removed=true;
            }


            curr=curr.next;

    count--;
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: probably because you are using reference comparisons `==`.  Try using `if(curr.data.equals(d))`

Comment: Can you please provide the definition of `curr` ?

Comment: I have already tried `if(curr.data.equals(d))` but it still same

Comment: the definition for curr is `private ListNode curr;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you're comparing Integer objects with `==`. Use the `equals()` method instead.

When you compare objects in Java using `==`, you compare them for *identity*, not for *equality*. The `==` will yield `true` if and only if both of its operands are the very same identical object. It will yield `false` in any other case, which includes the case in which the two operands are *equal but not same*.

Your code is using `Integer`, which is a class and therefore you can create two `Integer` objects which are equal but not same:

```
public static void equalsVsSameIntegerDemo() {
    final Integer i1 = new Integer(1);
    final Integer i2 = new Integer(1);
    System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); // true
    System.out.println(i1 == i2); // false
}
```

Alternatively, if you know it's `Integer` and it cannot be `null`, you could use `int` instead of `Integer`. But this only works if you're using `int` in the `remove`-method. If you use `int` in the caller, and call `remove(Object)`, the `int` would get converted into an `Integer`. If your ids are to be quite generic, you want to go for `equals()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have `if (curr.data==d)`

But are you sure that `new Integer(remId) == theObjectInsertedInTheList`?

I do not think so, and here lies your problem.

More info: [Object Equality](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072762/java-app-dev/object-equality.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the data of the node with `equals`, not with `==`, which just checks if the two are the same instance:

```
if(curr.data.equals(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using object identity to test for equality:

```
if (curr.data == d)
```

which is only true if the two operands are the *same* object, which they aren't. Change that line to:

```
if (curr.data.equals(d))
```

which compares the two objects' *values* (at least for the `Integer` class).

Answer (score 0):

Note that your algorithm will still fail even after you use the right comparison because your `fNode` and `curr` are not moving together.

When deleting, you are removing a given link from a chain -  let's say the chain is made of the following links: `A --> B --> C --> D`. Deleting `C` would mean removing the link that points from `B --> C` and and replacing it with a link that points from `B --> D`.
So you go from 
`A --> B --> C --> D` to
`A --> B --> D`

The algorithm, in pseudo code would be.

```
 1. start at the beginning of the list with the first node (Head of the list).
 2. check if it is the one you want to delete.
 3. if not, go to the next node and repeat step 2 
 4. if so, make the next node of the previous node the next node of this node
 5. remove the reference from this node to the next node
```